# writing text file in suspend state event handler in windows 8 html5

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs, filewriter

i am trying to write a text file when suspend event is fired i.e inside winjs.application.oncheckpoint event handler.
i am writing my object as JSON text.
here is the code:

```
        applicationData.localFolder.createFileAsync("dataFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (sampleFile) {
            var stringData = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0 ; i < myData.objData.length - 1 ; i++) {
                stringData += '{"title":"' + myData.objData[i].title + '","challange":"' + myData.objData[i].challange + '"},\n';
            }
            stringData += '{"title":"' + myData.objData[i].title + '","challange":"' + myData.objData[i].challange + '"}';
            stringData = "[" + stringData + "]";
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(sampleFile, stringData);
        }).done(function () { });
```

but windows app closes before writing anything into the text file.
I called args.setPromise() and passed the above code as a function parameter but same problem persists.

PS: i don't know how to do it asynchronously correctly.
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like Phil has commented, remove `.done()` will fix it.

This is because `done()` does not return anything whereas `then()` returns chained promise. That is the reason nothing is getting called.

It is also recommended to save your application data as soon as it changes or at some intervals and not wait for the suspend event to save everything. Suspend event gives time of 5s. otherwise, the app is terminated as per [msdn documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx).

*"If an app does not return from the suspending event within 5 seconds, Windows assumes that the app has stopped responding and terminates it"*

```
app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
app.sessionState.history = nav.history;

args.setPromise(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync
    ("dataFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (sampleFile) {
        var stringData;
        // code to set stringData.

        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(sampleFile, stringData);
    }));
```

};

Comment: works fine thanks for the help. but now if i close the app and again open it quickly it results in data loss.
i think i should write a file as soon as data changes.

Comment: yeah. saving it to file, and display user progress (progress ring) as part of such UI action should be better.

Answer (score 2):

Just `event.setPromise(applicationData.localFolder.createFileAsync ...)`

Then the suspend will wait until your promise finished. Remove the `.done`